# Syntax error when trying to run a Python file

Tags: python

File ex.py:

```
print('hello,word')
```

Trial run:

```
>>> d:\learning\python\ex.py

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: @sheepez The problem we see here has nothing to do with print...

Comment: @glglgl Very true, I will delete that comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the module:

```
>>> import ex
```

See the [documentation about modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

The module has to be [on your path or in the current working directory](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path). You can change directories using [**`chdir`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chdir):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir(r'd:\learning\python')

>>> import ex
hello,word
```

Or, in the command prompt, you can `set PYTHONPATH=d:\learning\python`, for example, before you start `python`, and `d:\learning\python` will get added to `sys.path`.

Instead, you could add it programatically:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.insert(0, r'd:\learning\python')

>>> import ex
hello,word
```

Comment: >>> import ex
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    import ex
ImportError: No module named 'ex'
>>>

Answer (score 3):

On the command line, outside the Python console, type:

```
python D:\learning\python\ex.py
```

Comment: Im using windows 7 and python is not recognised as an internal or external command

Comment: Okay, then type C:\Python27\python.exe or whatever the path is